# Using mouseClicked() to get to another image

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to make an I Spy game where when the object is clicked that needs to be found it brings you to the next level. I can not seem to get my mouse clicked to work with my images. I am a beginner so I am a bit confused as to why my if statement is not working.

```
//frame variables and inserting PImage
int numFrames = 3;
int frame = 0;
PImage[] image = new PImage[numFrames];

//setup- loading images
void setup() {
    size(800, 500);
    //load images first
    image[0] = loadImage("Kitchen_Scene.jpg");
    image[1] = loadImage("Plant_Scene.jpg");
    image[2] = loadImage("Interior_Car_Scene");
    imageMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {
    background(image[0]);
}

void mousePressed() {
    //(697,266)
    if ((mouseX > 697) && (mouseX < 727) && (mouseY > 266) && (mouseY < 306) {
        image[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: dude this is not the correct way for handling mouse clicks use event handlers instead

Comment: @JamalAl-kelani Tis is [processing](https://processing.org/) and `mousePressed` is an event!

Comment: Do you mean to use >= and <=?